# How do you configure a Node.js server to serve SVG files?

Tags: node.js, express, svg

I have built an app that serves an SVG file on a couple of the routes.  When I'm in localhost, the SVG shows up perfectly on the page, but on Heroku it is invisible.

In the network tab, while on Heroku, it shows that the SVG is returning as 'text/html' type, instead of 'svg+xml'.  I don't know why the file gets misinterpreted on Heroku, but not locally.  I would love to have a better idea of *why* that's happening.

I believe I have to configure the server to specify the svg content-type when it's called.  But how do I do this when my route is serving up different content-types all at once (json, text/html, etc.)?

Do I set a configuration in my `app.js` file, or in the route itself?  I tried using mime-types package.  I know this attempt is wrong, although it does log the correct content-type in the **server:**

```
router.get('/:category/:company', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("content type", mime.contentType(path.extname('../src/app/images/star-rating.icons.svg')));
  res.header("Content-Type", mime.contentType(path.extname('../src/app/images/star-rating.icons.svg')));

  Company.findOne({
    "companyName": req.params.company
  }, (err, company) => {
    // console.log("printing all reviews", company.reviews);
    if (!company) {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: "Can't find the company you're looking for at the moment."
      });
    } else {
      Review.find({
          '_id': {
            $in: company.reviews
          }
        })
        .populate("createdBy")
        .exec((err, review) => {
          if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
          } else {
            res.json({
              message: "Retrieving your company",
              company: company,
              reviews: review
            });

            console.log("returning review", review);
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

I tried `res.setHeader` as well, and tried including both in my else statement above my `res.json`.  I've been pouring through lots of S.O. questions, but can't seem to nail this issue down.  Any help or insight on what is happening and/or efficient solutions would be so. damn. appreciated.

Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT:  Some server code

```
//Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

//Attempt to make svg file in assets public to browser, here:
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/images')));


//Set our api routes
app.use('/', api);
app.use('/', auth);



//Allows the use of /server filepath when serving uploaded user images
app.use('/server', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/server')));



//Catch all other routes and return the index file.
//Catch-all route MUST come after all other API routes have been defined.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));

});


// Get port from environment and store in Express
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

// Create HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost: ${port}`));
```

Comment: Try making the images folder public, like this (`app.use(express.static('../src/app/images')`), so that you can access if from browser

Comment: Thank you for your answer @HelloWorld.  I tried adding it, but I'm facing the same issue.  I'm going to include some of the code from my server.js for context, since I already have a static path in there.

Comment: Have you tried to access it from the browser like this(`http://<domain-name>//star-rating.icons.svg`) ??
After adding this in your server.js file `app.use(express.static('../src/app/images')`??